# Starting a session after site log on

Tags: php, html, session

I am trying to understand starting and destroying sessions. I have successfully created Login and Signup forms respectively, but I am having a difficult time creating sessions within those forms. I have a session.php file (for the login), connect.php file (for the signup), indexHome.html (homepage it routes to), and indexLS.html (the login page).

session.php and connect.php both have `session_start();` at the top of the file, but when I put`session_start();` at the top of my indexHome.html, the text shows up as if I wrote paragraph tags in an html file. However, I think it does successfully start the session because my favicon changes to a XAMPP icon.

I'm not sure what the standard practice is (how to really do it), so I appreciate any help. Thanks!

````
<php>
session_start();
</php>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
...
</html>```
````

Comment: You can't run PHP in .html files because the server does not recognize that as a valid PHP extension unless you tell it to.

Comment: <?php
session_start();
?> not <php></php> https://www.w3resource.com/php/syntax/syntax.php

Comment: @Jdub So then 1) Should I tell it to and if so how can I go about doing that or 2) is there a better way to do it that doesn't involve changing my home page to a PHP file or is that the best method. I don't want to screw up my whole project by changing the file to a PHP file.

Comment: Would definitely recommend just making it a php file and fixing your references to it. Very likely going to be the easiest option.

Comment: @abney317 Ok. Will do. Thanks for the recommendation!